# Is it possible to reference a declared thrift const in the thrift file?

Tags: thrift

trivial example

```
struct SomeStruct {
  1: required i16 value
}

const SomeStruct CON1 = {"value": 11 };
const SomeStruct CON2 = CON1;
const list<SomeStruct> SOME_LIST = [CON1, CON2];
```

fails to compile, targeting ruby

```
[FAILURE] type error: const "CON2" was declared as struct/xception
```

thrift --gen rb 
thrift version 0.9.0

it seems something like this works with twitter/scrooge but not the apache compiler

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the declaration of CON2.

I'm not sure about this one. There's a test in the compiler which tests for various types and stuff, but from the [IDL spec](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/idl) it should be a legal construct. I'd recommend to

a) work around by specifying

```
const SomeStruct CON1 = {"value": 11 };
const SomeStruct CON2 = {"value": 11 };
```

and b) file a [JIRA ticket](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT)